# Use NTLM authentication with Ingress, NGINX and Docker containers

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes-ingress, ntlm

I have an ASP.NET Core project running in a client in IIS using NTLM authentication.

They're migrating all systems to docker containers. These containers run under NGINX, which then runs under INGRESS.

I know it is a very broad question, but in this scenario, is it possible to continue using NTLM authentication through all these layers?